# ggplot: plotting more than one function on one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a task to plot histogram using my data ([here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UTra4ED6n2mTeavBx7v0eq0ngo9e6ZMA/view?usp=sharing)) named `NoPodsWeight`, its density and normal distribution for this segment (`min(NoPodsWeight)` and `max(NoPodsWeight)`).
I am trying this:

```
myframe <- read.csv(filepath, fileEncoding = "UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
myframe <- myframe[rowSums(is.na(myframe)) <= 0,]
nopodsweight <- myframe$NoPodsWeight
height <- myframe$Height
ggplot(myframe, aes(x = NoPodsWeight, y = ..density..)) + 
   geom_histogram(color="black", fill="white") + 
   geom_density(color = "blue") +
   stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(myframe$NoPodsWeight), sd = sd(myframe$NoPodsWeight)))
```

Using this code I get an error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be valid computed stats. Problematic aesthetic(s): y =
> ..density...
> Did you map your stat in the wrong layer?

I don't understand how to plot two or more functions on one plot. For example I can solve my problem using standard `plot` (but without density):

```
 hist(x = nopodsweight, freq = F, ylim = c(0, 0.45), breaks = 37)
 n_norm<-seq(min(nopodsweight)-1, max(nopodsweight)+1, 0.0001)
 lines(n_norm, dnorm(n_norm), col = "red")
```

[image]

Is there any function in `ggplot` to plot (normal) distribution (or maybe using another function) like in `lines`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take `..density..` out of the `ggplot()` layer and put it specifically in the `geom_histogram` layer. I didn't download and import your data, but here's an example on `mtcars`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) +
  geom_density(color = "blue") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(mtcars$mpg), sd = sd(mtcars$mpg)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The error message says "did you map your stat in the wrong layer?"; that's a hint.  Moving `aes(y=..density..)` to apply specifically to `geom_histogram()` seems to make everything OK ...

```
ggplot(myframe, aes(x = NoPodsWeight)) + 
    geom_histogram(color="black", fill="white",
                 aes(y = ..density..)) + 
 ## [... everything else ...]
```